# How to add a static route in systemd-networkd?

Tags: networking, systemd, route, systemd-networkd

I have a host which is on `192.168.0.0/24` with an IP of `192.168.0.13`. Its DHCP-provided gateway is `192.168.0.254`.

The configuration is done via `systemd-networkd` and the issue below is present at least until version `240` (the version I use today - see my answer regarding further versions).

I need this host to reach `10.0.0.0/8` networks which are available through a `192.168.0.10` gateway - this can be done by adding a static route:

```
# ip r add 10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.0.10
```

**It works fine (the traffic goes through).**

I now wanted to add this entry to my `systemd-networkd` configuration, by adding a `[Route]` to my curent definition

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

# the entry below is added to ensure a static route

[Route]
Gateway=192.168.0.10
Destination=10.0.0.0/8
```

It does not work:

- no static route is added
- there is an error message in the log mentioning an unreachable network

```
Jan 17 11:29:32 rpi-dmz systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
Jan 17 11:29:32 rpi-dmz systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Jan 17 11:29:32 rpi-dmz systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Jan 17 11:29:33 rpi-dmz systemd-networkd[14584]: wlan0: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 17 11:29:33 rpi-dmz systemd-networkd[14584]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Jan 17 11:29:33 rpi-dmz systemd-networkd[14584]: Enumeration completed
Jan 17 11:29:33 rpi-dmz systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Jan 17 11:29:33 rpi-dmz systemd-networkd[14584]: eth0: Could not set route: Network is unreachable
Jan 17 11:29:33 rpi-dmz systemd-networkd[14584]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.0.13/24 via 192.168.0.254
```

**How to correctly add that route via `systemd-networkd`?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### This is [a bug in `systemd`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1850), still present on version `240`.

Per the thread above, a workaround (or solution, I am not sure about the status since the bug is still open) is to add `GatewayOnlink=yes` in the `[Route]` section:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[Route]
Gateway=192.168.0.10
Destination=10.0.0.0/8
GatewayOnLink=yes
```

This parameter is available from `systemd` version ~237.

Comment: FWIW I would agree this is an open bug in systemd. The equivalent settings in NetworkManager work without hitting this problem; I think it is very reasonable for people to expect that the very similar-looking options in `systemd-networkd` will also work.  It is undesirable for them to have to discover this does not work by experiment and have to look in the log - and then even when you look at the log messages, it is not very helpful.

Comment: I don't know what the best behaviour would be though.  I see "Note that DHCPv6 will by default be triggered by [receiving a packet of type] Router Advertisement, if that is enabled..."

Comment: @WoJ `GatewayOnlink` has been deprecated in favour of `GatewayOnLink` since `242`. Worth updating the answer.

Comment: In my case I got `Could not set route: No route to host`, and `GatewayOnlink=yes` fixes it for me. Tested on systemd 241 and 246.

Comment: @tambre I stumbled upon this question when searching for the problem, found my own question and answer, saw your comment, and tadaa! fixed after only four years almost day to day :)